# Thymeleaf or JSON to send data?

Tags: javascript, json, servlets, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I have to pass an array of data from a Java controller to a dynamic web page. Both the webpage and the controller belong to the same application and I have access to both of them. 
In order to program the dynamic behaviour all of my webpages I use Thymeleaf. 
In one of those pages there is a JavaScript code and there is the possibility to use Thymeleaf inside it. 
My question is: what are the pros and cons of using JSON and Thymeleaf to pass those data? Which one is more efficient?

Thank you!

Comment: thymeleaf vs JSON ? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, if I use JSON I have to request the data to a servlet that gives them back, while if I use Thymeleaf I can pass them directly to the webpage using the servlet

Comment: @want2learn why do you think it makes no sense? If I want to use those data I might use both Thymeleaf and JSON

Comment: Thymeleaf and JSON are two entirely different things and one is not substitute of other.

Comment: @want2learn I completely agree with you: they are entirely different things, but in some particular situations both of them might be used to reach the same final result

Comment: For example, if my page is a leaflet map, I might use JSON to collect data and to put some markers on the map or I might send the same data using Thymeleaf, and they will be available for reading in JS, too. Of course the JS code will show every single marker creation when the user opens it, but my question is not about style: it is about how fast those two solutions are and which one is better in your opinion.